# Duplicate foreign keys in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have a table like the following:

- a (**id**, *b.id*, *c.id*)
- b (**id**)
- c (**id**)

On table a, I would like to have fields that are foreign keys of b.id and c.id. However, having the same combination of b and c foreign keys should only be allowed once. For instance, if b.id=1 and c.id=1 (in table a foreign keys) it is fine, but there cannot be another record with b.id=1 and c.id=1, etc.

I'm using MySQL, how do I alter my database to enforce this?

Comment: make combination as unique key.

Comment: i have given example as answer check it. It will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `a` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`b.id`, `c.id`);
```

so, in this combination your value will always be unique and other value will not insert.

Comment: It my pleasure to help someone.

Answer (score 2):

you can create unique index on b.id and c.id

```
ALTER TABLE `a` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `unique_b_c` (`b.id`, `c.id`);
```

Comment: This is what I needed, Manoj was just a little quicker. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

ALTER TABLE `a` 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `myindex` (`b.id`, `c.id`);